# How to pronounce the name שימי

Tags: names, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters, amoroim

There's an [*amora*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amora) (or at least one) in the *Bavli* named שימי. I think I've always heard this pronounced with an initial letter *sin*. However, I saw recently that the Koren-Steinsaltz edition has a initial *shin*. What support is there for either?

Comment: Good question; a look at Alfred Kolatch's *Masters of the Talmud: Their Lives and Views* shows me that he lists about a dozen amoraim named Shimi (one of whom is Shimi bar Abba) and one named Simi - Simi bar Abba, in fact. Seder haDorot notes the existence of two named שימי בר אבא, but says nothing about the pronunciation.

Comment: I've always assumed it was Shimi. More likely a nickname for Shimon or the like. Not so likely to be a nonjewish name starting with sin, out would've started with a samech as most Aramaic words with an S sound do.

Answer (score 1):

[Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A9%D6%B4%D7%81%D7%99%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99?lang=bi) identifies him as Shimi:

> שִׁימִי pr. n. m. Shimi, name of several Amoraim. Men. 29ᵃ, a. fr. ש׳ בר חייא. Ib. ש׳ את art thou Shimi (and askest such a question)?; ib. 110ᵃ. Tem. 28ᵃ ש׳ בר אשי; a. e.

Moreover, search results for 'Shimi' on Sefaria yeild [229](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=shimi&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) results, while 'Simi' only [5](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=simi&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance).

However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simi_bar_Chiya) calls him Simi.

[Who's Who in the Talmud](https://books.google.com/books?id=9PToGLIBt6UC&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=,%20Rav%20Shimi%20bar%20Chiya&source=bl&ots=t2MF_hOea_&sig=ACfU3U2HMTbjrAHWkKh_Q1VfFsb-nNmT5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwmZLLwf_fAhWRiOAKHZ2fD5EQ6AEwCXoECAcQAQ#v=snippet&q=Shimi&f=false) only contains Shimi and no Simi.

Interestingly, it is difficult to tell how Rav Kanievsky pronounces it [here](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Media/PlayShiur.aspx?FileName=Daf_007_0545-20130305-034400-D_007.mp3&ShiurNum=20) (9:25).

But [here](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Media/PlayShiur.aspx?FileName=Daf_021_0545-20130305-120500-D_021.mp3&ShiurNum=6) (5:12) it sounds more like Simi, and [here](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Media/PlayShiur.aspx?FileName=Daf_002_0545-20130305-004200-D_002.mp3&ShiurNum=58) (9:22) more like Shimi.

Comment: Wikipedia might call him Simi because Greek lacks the "sh" sound. Consider Saul in the Septuagint versus Shaul.

Comment: Rav Kanievsky might have Sobosdiker Losen though. But you can't really tell from the recording.