# Rava and Rabbah? Differentiating between two (?) amoraim

Tags: talmud-gemara, names, grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, amoroim

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53748/how-to-pronounce-the-name-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99), I have often heard people pronounce the name רבא as Rava and the name רבה as Rabbah. Is there a basis for this differentiation? Does anybody know where it comes from?

Comment: I think that's how the grammar specifies them to be.

Comment: @Cnsermoit In Aramaic the word רבא is pronounced rabba. Look at the Targum (which has nekudos) any time the word comes up. If in fact the amoras name was pronounced this way and not Rava,it would explain why the two names are mixed up so often.

Comment: I've also heard this. I believe that it's a big stretch to say that רבא and רבה are the same person, because there are some instances where they argue with each other (rather famously, [Gittin 2a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=2&format=pdf)-b).

Comment: @Shokhet someone suggested they were the same person?

Comment: @user6591 I thought that's what the title was saying...but I might have misread it.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but in Yeshiva we were (somewhat ironically) taught "יהא שמיה רבא", explained as, "If it is a 'ה', his name is Rabbah"

Comment: @shokhet - sorry, my title was an allusion to the fact that there were *more* than just two people with those names! I definitely don't think they were both the same person (though I've no doubt that sometimes copyists got confused - I think there's some variation in the manuscript tradition).

Comment: `@ShimonbM It's all right. Copyists do get confused sometime: there are plenty of times that Tosfos mention that it's really one or the other of them in a specific gemara. @Menachem; I've heard the same as well :)

Comment: @ShimonbM it comes from the fact that they are two different people. As far as nekudot, it might be a mesorah.

Answer (score 1):

רַבָּה is written explicitly in the Torah the way we pronounce it in Bereishis 26,14: וַיְהִי לוֹ מִקְנֵה צֹאן וּמִקְנֵה בָקָר וַעֲבֻדָּה **רַבָּה**.

Its a name of a place in Samuel  12,27 and Chronicles 1 20,1: נִלְחַ֣מְתִּי בְ**רַבָּ֔ה** גַּם־לָכַ֖דְתִּי אֶת־עִ֥יר הַמָּֽיִם

It is also a name in Yechezkel 5,5: וְנָתַתִּ֤י אֶת־**רַבָּה֙**

It is also name of a place/person in Jeremiah 49:3 צְעַקְנָה֮ בְּנ֣וֹת **רַבָּה֒**

But רָבָא is not explicitly written anywhere in tenach so in order to differentiate between the 2 names, the minhag is that we pronounce it with a kometz under the Reish and a komeitz under the beis and then the beis automatically doesn't have a dageish and is pronounced Rovo (ashkenazi) or Rava (sefaradi) which sounds different to Rabo or raba.

These are example of words wich the 2 letters before the end have 2 komeitzs ther is no dageish in the letter before the end:
Bereishis 11,3:**הָבָה** נִלְבְּנָה לְבֵנִים

Bereishis 11,4:**הָבָה** נִבְנֶה לָּנוּ עִיר

Bereishis 11,7: **הָבָה** נֵרְדָה וְנָבְלָה שָׁם שְׂפָתָם

Bereishis 29,21 applies toa noun:וַיֹּאמֶר יַעֲקֹב אֶל **לָבָן** הָבָה אֶת אִשְׁתִּי

And here is a Noun in Melachim 1 15,8וַיִּמְלֹ֛ךְ **אָסָ֥א** בְנ֖וֹ תַּחְתָּֽיו

In Aramaic as well we find the word **הָכָ֑א** (which means here") many many times where the a kometz under the first letter and a komeitz under the second letter which drops the dageish just like רָבָא

Also **בָּבָא** appears many times which means gate and is a noun has the same rule as רָבָא.

So רָבָא is  grammatically correct without a dageish in the Beis.